# Having trouble identifying the null terminator in a simple string

Tags: c

This is a simple "hello, world" program to practice with file i/o and while loops. I'm having trouble identifying the null terminator. I think the problem is a `char` / `int` conflict. I don't know how to handle it. Can anyone solve the problem using the null terminator to identify the end of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n = 0;
    char ch[] = "Hello, world!";

    FILE *out_file = fopen("hello.txt", "w");

    while (n < 10)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) /*Would prefer to use the null character.*/
            fputc(ch[i], out_file);

        fputc('\n', out_file);
        n++;
    }

    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine with `< 13` as the condition. But I would prefer to refer to the null terminator.

Comment: Do you know how to use `strlen`? Alternatively, you can keep increasing the index until the current character is equal to `'\0'`

Comment: Just loop `for (i = 0; ch[i]; i++) { fputc(ch[i], out_file); }` The nul-terminating character is there to identify the end of the string -- use it. (or better just use `fputs()` or `fprintf()` and be done with it...)

Comment: "I think the problem is a char / int conflict" Maybe it would be useful to show the code that might have that conflict. In the code you show, you don't try to use the terminator. If you want to solve a problem, it is best to show the code that is not working instead some other solution that works.

Comment: You need to show the code that causes trouble, not the one that works. Read this: [mcve].

Answer (score 4):

Here is your code adapted per your request: the loop will break on the terminating NUL ('\0') of the string "Hello, world!"

[Here](https://godbolt.org/z/6ePn581Gq) is runnable, tested code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int n = 0;
    char ch[] = "Hello, world!";

    FILE *out_file = fopen("hello.txt", "w");

    while(n < 10)
    {
        /* for() is updated. The loop will break at the terminating NUL.
        * When ch[i] encounters the NUL, the condition in the for() loop 
        * will no longer be true, and the loop will break. */
        for(i = 0; ch[i]; i++) 
            fputc(ch[i], out_file);

        fputc('\n', out_file);
        n++;
    }
    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: People forget how flexible the `for` statement is, think it's only good for fixed counts.

Answer (score 2):

As other have answered, replace `i < 13` with a *null character* test such as `ch[i] != '\0'`.

```
   int i;
   ...
        // for(i = 0; i < 13; i++)
        for(i = 0; ch[i] != '\0'; i++)
        // or simply
        for(i = 0; ch[i]; i++)
```

Although uncommon, a *string* may have a length more than `INT_MAX`.  For array indexing, use the *unsigned* type `size_t`.  It is neither too narrow nor too wide.  It's size is [just right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldilocks_and_the_Three_Bears#Literary_elements).

```
#include <stdlib.h>

   // int i;
   size_t i;
   ...
        for(i = 0; ch[i]; i++)
```

Or even slightly simpler:

```
   // int i;
   ...
        for(size_t i = 0; ch[i]; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just simplify this a little bit with `fprintf` and use `for` in place of that `while` loop. The `%s` format specifier will print the string up to the null terminator without the manual loop and printing characters.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char ch[] = "Hello, world!";

    FILE *out_file = fopen("hello.txt", "w");

    for (int n = 0; n < 10; n++) {
        fprintf(out_file, "%s\n", ch);
    }

    fclose(out_file);

    return 0;
}
```

Here the call to `fprintf` replaces all of the below:

```
        for (char *i = ch; *i; i++) {
            fputc(*i, out_file);
        }

        fputc('\n', out_file);
```